# How to write this RegExp /^\s*FirstName\s*$/ using a variable? I want to replace FirstName with a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write the RegExp that begins with either the space or the word, but I want to pass the word using the variable. Does anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Did you try [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

Regex express is just a normal string, you can replace the variable with string method and then use it as pattern.
For example:

```js
const getPattern = function (placeholder) {
  return new RegExp(`\\s*${placeholder}\\s*$`);
}
const matcher = getPattern('firstName');
console.log(matcher.exec('my firstName '));
```

Comment: OP question tagged `js` not `py`

Comment: @wei thx, the example has been modified.